# Return type of "this" in virtual functions

Tags: c++, covariant-return-types

In the code I'm giving you, there is `E` that derives from `C`, and I have a pointer to an object of `C`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C {
  public: virtual C* f(){ cout << "C::f()" << endl; return this; }
};

class E: public C {
  public: E* f(){ cout << "E::f()" << endl; return this; }
};

int main(){
  C* pc = new E;
  auto p = pc->f();
  cout << typeid(p).name() << endl;
}
```

When I call `pc->f()`, it goes to `E::f()` due to the `virtual` function, and I get it, but what is the return type of `return this;`?

Because `this` is a `C*`, but in the signature the method should return an `E*`.

If you run it, it prints:

```
E::f()
P1C
```

Comment: You have `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(p), C*>);` i.e. `auto` IS `C*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `p` *is* `C*`, but the object it points to is an `E`.

If you print the typename of `*p`, you get (mangled) `E`.

```
cout << typeid(p).name() << endl << typeid(*p).name() << endl;
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07ea958a51c7511e)

When you call `f` through an `E*`, you get an `E*` back.

```
int main(){
  E* pe = new E;
  C* pc = pe;
  auto p1 = pe->f();
  auto p2 = pc->f();
  cout << typeid(E).name() << endl << typeid(C).name() << endl;
  cout << typeid(p1).name() << endl << typeid(p2).name() << endl;
  cout << typeid(*p1).name() << endl << typeid(*p2).name() << endl;
}
```

[More coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4028c94576f92d63)

Comment: So it returns a C* that points to an E object?

Comment: when called through a `C*` yes

Comment: Yes. Its totally valid to have `C* c = new E();` And the runtime type of `*c` is `E`.

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
class E: public C{
  public: E* f(){cout << "E::f()" << endl; return this;}
};
```

a pointer to `E*` is returned. `this` is pointer to the current object, an `E`.

> Because this is a `C*` but in the signature the method should return an `E*`.

No, `this` is a pointer to `E*` and `E*` can be converted to `C*`. It is called "covariant return type". In a nutshell: It is ok for `E::f` to return an `E*` even though it overrides `C::f` which returns a `C*`. That is because `E` inherits publicly from `C` and `E*` can be converted to `C*`.

For a caller that expects the signature as declared in `C` there is no issue:

```
 void foo(C& c) {
     C* p = c.f();  // OK!   
 }
```

---

> But then why typeid tells it's a C*?

First of all you need to take care about the names. They are arbitrary. Looking only at the output of a single type name cannot tell with certainty what type it is.

Then you should do this to get the full picture:

```
cout << typeid(C).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(E).name() << endl; 
cout << typeid(p).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*p).name() << endl;
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3hrG8ac8f):

```
1C
1E
P1C
1E
```

`p` is a `C*`, thats the signature of `C::f` the virtual function you called, but the object it points to is an `E`.

Comment: But then why typeid tells it's a C*?

Comment: @matteocamillo typeid says its a `P1C`. Those names are arbitrary. Did you actually check what `typeid(C).name()` and `typeid(B).name()` are?

Comment: Because `auto` is a compile time type, and all the compiler knows is that it has got a `C` and the return type of `C::f` is a `C*`. And so the type of `p` will always be `C*`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks, the second part of the message answered my question

Comment: @matteocamillo sorry I got confused and missed this part of the question because you assumed `P1C` is pointer to C without checking, but I suppose thats just my pedantry ;)